# loop through a collection of classes and recognize them for adding a new one

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, class, loops

I've got a set of classes with propperties and a main class which has lists of the set of classes.

```
public class MainClass
{
    public List<ClassA> listA {get;set;}
    public List<ClassB> listB {get;set;}
    public List<ClassC> listC {get;set;}

    public object[] loop = {listA, listB, listC};
}

class ClassA
{
    public Guid id {get;set;}
    public string text {get;set;}
    public int number {get;set}

    public status {get;set;}
    public object[] loop = {id, text, number};
}
class ClassB
{
    public Guid id {get;set;}
    public string text {get;set;}
    public Image pic {get;set}

    public status {get;set;}
    public object[] loop = {id, text, pic};
}
class ClassC
{
    public Guid id {get;set;}
    public byte[] data {get;set;}
    public DateTime date {get;set;}

    public status {get;set;}
    public object[] loop = {id, data, date};
}

public enum status
{
    nothing=0, instert=1, delete=2, edit=3
}
```

Situation has changed since yesterday but still, i'd like to index my class, my idea was by adding this line:

```
public object[] loop = {listA, listB, listC};
```

to MainClass, archieving this goal, after changing the whole thing to an non static class it seems forbidden. also when i was trying this with a static class i cant adress my lists directly. could this be done any how?

finaly i want to adress a specific property inside the list like this:

```
MainClass mc = new MainClass();
DateTime dt = mc.loop[2][5].loop[2];
```

even if it would be nicer to do this without the loop property, like:

```
DateTime dt = mc[2][5][2];
```

how i want to loop it finaly:

```
for(int i=0; i<mc.loop.count(); i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<mc.loop[i].Count(); i++)
    {
        switch(mc.loop[i][j].loop[3])
        {
            case: delete
                doSomething1(mc.loop[i][j])
            case: insert
                doSomething2(mc.loop[i][j])
            case: edit
                 doSomething3(mc.loop[i][j])
            default
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is fundamentally confused. Is your goal to set default values on the properties on the classes? Just do it in the constructors of `ClassA`, `ClassB`, etc. instead.

Comment: actualy my plan is to fill a class based copy of a multi-table sql-database with a short code, where i dont need to adress every class and its property individualy. instead i want to loop through the parent class and fill the lists of childclasses from its fitting datatable, so i need not only a loop, i also need to recognize which kind of class im using at the specific moment to take the specific sql-table

Comment: Sounds like a basic reflection tutorial chould point you the right direction.

Comment: Why don't you just choose an existing ORM framework (NHibernate, EF)? What you are doing now, if implemented properly, leads to that functionality anyway, and this way you are just reinventing the wheel and spending your time on plumbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've written in my comment, you should simply go for a [Object-Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) framework, since you are obviously trying to abstract the mapping from your domain into the database.

That being said, you can generalize the whole thing using Reflection. Provided that you don't intend to add complex mapping rules, you would have something similar to:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in myClass.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var name = propertyInfo.Name;
    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(myClass);

    // do stuff
    Console.WriteLine("Value of {0} is {1}", name, value ?? "null");
}
```

A proper ORM does a lot more than this. If allows you to define specific mapping rules for each property. Nested objects and automatic mapping of one-to-many relations. It does lots of complex caching to avoid performance penalty associated with reflection (and more important, database access). It allows lazy access to the database by deferring queries until data is needed. It tracks which properties are changed and automatically updates them. And all that by including a reference to a library, spending a day or two looking at examples (and asking stuff on Stack Overflow) and writing a mapping configuration file.

Or, you can define [mappings through code](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started) to get full intellisense and better type safety:

```
// fluent nhibernate example
public class CatMap : ClassMap<Cat>
{
    public CatMap()
    {
        // define which properties are going to be saved, and how
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name).Length(16).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Sex);
        References(x => x.Mate);
        HasMany(x => x.Kittens);
    }
}
```

What you are doing right now is a maintenance nightmare. You are enforcing a rule where each data class needs to expose its properties as an object array (and think about how you would *update* their values this way). Also, you lose all type safety because you end up with plain objects. The only way for you to know which property you are accessing is by the index of the `loop` array, meaning you are going for lots of `if` conditions and magic numbers all over your code. As an exercise of how things shouldn't be done, it's fine, but don't allow this to end up in production code or you will spend countless hours fixing bugs and changing code to add new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
MainClass mc = new MainClass();
DateTime dt = ((ClassA) mc.loop[2]).date;
```

Still I am not sure what you really want and what are all those indexes for...

Comment: what i want ist the oportunity of looping my class mc automaticly. see edit above.

Comment: in that case you can edit the properties to store variables to the object arrays, but it is sort of ugly design.

Comment: could you give me an example? idk exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

1) to discard the loop variable you can create class indexer like this

```
private object[] loop = {id, text, number};
public int this[int index]
{
    get { return loop[index]; }
    set { loop[index] = value; }
}
```

2) to be able to retrieve the variables you would probably have to cast them from object to their actual types to be able to use their capabilities. it is still unpractical.

```
DateTime dt = ((DateTime) ((ClassA)mc[0]) [2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure what you are doing but how about this

```
public enum Status
{
    Nothing = 0,
    Insert,
    Delete,
    Edit
}

public abstract class Searchable
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    protected internal abstract IEnumerable SearchableProperties { get; }
}

public class ClassA : Searchable
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    protected internal override IEnumerable SearchableProperties
    {
        get
        {
            yield return Text;
            yield return Number;
        }
    }
}

public class ClassB : Searchable
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Image Pic { get; set; }
    protected internal override IEnumerable SearchableProperties
    {
        get
        {
            yield return Text;
            yield return Pic;
        }
    }
}

public class ClassC : Searchable
{
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    protected internal override IEnumerable SearchableProperties
    {
        get
        {
            yield return Data;
            yield return Date;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write your main class like this,

```
public class Searchables
{
    public List<ClassA> ListA { get; set; }
    public List<ClassB> ListB { get; set; }
    public List<ClassC> ListC { get; set; }

    public void SearchContents(Action<Status, Searchable, object> visitor)
    {
        SearchContent(this.ListA, visitor);
        SearchContent(this.ListB, visitor);
        SearchContent(this.ListC, visitor);
    }

    private static void SearchContent(
            IEnumerable<Searchable> searchees,
            Action<Status, Searchable, object> visitor)
    {
        foreach (var searchee in searchees)
        {
            visitor(searchee.Status, searchee, searchee.Id);
            foreach (var property in searchee.SearchableProperties)
            {
                visitor(searchee.Status, searchee, property);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do is write the visitor ...

```
var mainClass = new Searchables();

....

mainClass.SearchContent((status, searchee, property) =>
    {
        switch(status)
        {
            case Status.Delete:
                // DoSomthing1 ...
                break;
        }
    });
```

but, that bit is not in your question.

Comment: This will also pretty much suck, because: 1. OP still needs to create these lists manually (I don't see much difference between an `Array` and a manually written `IEnumerable`, 2. There is no metadata which shows which property you are accessing, 3. There is no way to set a value of a property. So IMHO it simply adds a lot more overhead (true, with better naming) to basically specifying an `interface` like `ISearchable { object[] loop { get; } }`, without actually solving anything.

Comment: @Groo, what metadata should be provided that will help? What does the OP want to do once he can iterate over all the properties.

Comment: Check OP's comment below the question. It's basically used to interact with an SQL database. So I am saying it will be hard to create a `SELECT` query without knowing names of these properties, and hard to set these values after the data is fetched from the DB. The only thing he can do with this code is create an `INSERT` query, and have fixed column names in that query which correspond to the order of properties. He also doesn't have any control over formatting of these values and converting them to appropriate SQL values. My strong feeling is he is heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Groo, you are right, this is essentailly a fools errand that has more to do with a half baked ORM than the searching of properties. I'd already gone of on a tangent and didn't get or read all the question updates. As you say in your answer, theres little point trying to reinvent one of many specialised alternatives.